# postgres query to return only id and count with max count

Tags: postgresql

How can I display ONLY `id` 4 and 2 because they have the highest count?

```
SELECT id, count(*) FROM followers GROUP BY id ORDER BY 2 DESC;

id count
4  4
2  4
1  3
3  2
```

expected outout

```
id count
4  4
2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Common Table Expression (CTE) like below:

```
 WITH counts AS ( 
 SELECT id, count(*) AS cnt FROM followers GROUP BY id)
 SELECT * FROM counts where cnt = (select MAX(cnt) from counts)
```